# what should be the details of an onEdit event?

Tags: google-apps-script

I read the doc for the [Spreadsheet Edit Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_events#TriggerAttributes) but if I test which details are passed with a simple function:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.toast(Object.keys(e));
}
```

I get **source,user**

Is it a bug or is the doc outdated/wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's documentation only for the on edit event when using a "installable trigger" (the one you set from the menu). The simple event handler (the one you're testing) only receives source and user, as you noticed.

And the `e.source` is already the active spreadsheet, so you don't need to `getActiveSpreadsheet()`. And you can get the active/modified range by issuing a `e.source.getActiveRange()`.

The `user` information is only filled if its yourself or your in a Apps domain account and also the active user.